# Communication with sim

Tags: android, sim-card

I am new in hardware operating development in android.I am going to communicate with the SIM only which is attached with the hardware device.When i am giving instruction with help of android application it goes to the hardware attached SIM perform a particular operation.Can any one provide me guidance for developing this task.

can any one provide me a simcard famework & documentation for android like [available in .net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET)

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: can any one give me answer of that question

Answer (score 0):

you can send APDU (commands)  to card a common applet or standard (SIM/USIM/UICC) applet to handle the card it self (update file, install/remove/disable applets etc ....). I recommend u to read this [document](http://miun.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:423013/FULLTEXT02.pdf#page=18&zoom=auto,69,355) its may help (very good overview of the SIM card environment).

before you start development you need at least to understand the basic of cards  this  video could also help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31D94QOo2gY